# React Typescript 関数の引数の書き方

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-jsx

#### 前提・実現したいこと

親コンポーネントで子コンポーネントに渡す関数を定義したいのですが、引数をどう書いたらいいのかがわかりません。
わかる人がいたら教えて欲しいです

#### 該当のソースコード

```
**types.ts**
export type Task {
  id: number
  text: string
  done: boolean
}
```

```
//親コンポーネント
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Task } from './Types'

// 初期値を設定
const  inisialState:Task[] = [
  {
    id: 0,
    text: "",
    done: false,
  }
]

const App: React.FC = () => {
    const [text, setText] = useState('')
    const [task, setTask] = useState(inisialState);


//チェックボックスが押された時の処理　　（ListItem(子)に渡したい）
    const　handleCheck = (何を入れたらいいのか) => {
        setTasks(prev => prev.map(t =>
            t.id === task.id
                ? { ...task, done: !task.done }
                : t
        ))
    }
 // 削除ボタンが押された時の処理　（ListItem(子)に渡したい）
    const handleDelete = (何を入れたらいいのか) => {
        setTasks(prev => prev.filter(t =>
            t.id !== task.id
        ))
    }


    return (
　　　　　　〜省略〜
        <div>
            <TaskList/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
子コンポーネント
import React from 'react'
import TaskItem from './TaskItem'
import { Task } from './Types'

interface Props {
  text: string
  tasks:　task[]
  handleCheck:  
  handleDelete: 
}


const TaskList: React.FC<Props> = ({props}) => {

    return (

   ~ 省略〜
    )
}

export default TaskList
```

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/235536

Answer (score -1):

親から子に値を渡すには、render() の中で、例えば

```
render() {
  return (
    <ChildComponent
      listItem={this.state.listItem}
      onChange={this.handleChange} />
  );
}
```

のように、親コンポーネントから子コンポーネントをレンダリングするタイミングで渡します。

「何を入れたらいいのか」の部分は、子コンポーネントからの返り値を親コンポーネントに渡すときに使います。例えば子コンポーネントでListItemが更新されたとすると、親コンポーネントがその更新されたデータを受け取り、stateに反映するかどうかなど判定するなどして、

```
handleChange(updatedElementId, data) {
  const updatedItems = this.state.listItems.slice();
  updatedItems[updatedElementId] = data;
  this.setState({
    listItems: updatedItems
  });
}
```

のようにします。
データはあくまで親コンポーネントが子コンポーネントをレンダーするときのみ渡し、子コンポーネントでデータが更新されたときは子コンポーネントがonChangeを通して親コンポーネントのhandleChangeに報告する、そして親コンポーネントのthis.stateを更新して再び子コンポーネントにデータを渡して新しいデータでレンダーする、という流れになります。